# How to download android support library 25.1.0 via curl?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-sdk-manager

I need to download android support library 25.1.0 and google repo 10.0.1 via curl (behind GFW) but I cannot find the link via recent Android SDK xml. How can I find archived packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Addons**: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml

Ctrl+F "librar". Find the url for the **m2repository**: `android_m2repository_r47.zip`.

Then use curl to download the file:

[https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repositor‌​y_r47.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repositor%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8By_r47.zip).